# I want to scrape the reviews through selenium webscraping and make a csv file of it but finding hard to remove the error. How to remove error?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nlp

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import sqlite3 as sql

urls = []
product_urls = []
list_of_reviews = []


# Each page urls
for i in range(1, 252):
    urls.append(f"https://www.etsy.com/in-en/c/jewelry/earrings/ear-jackets-and-climbers?ref=pagination&explicit=1&page={i}")

# Scraping each product's urls | 16,064 products
for url in urls:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\dell\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(5)
    for i in range(1, 65):
        product = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[{i}]/div/a'))
        product_urls.append(product.get_attribute('href'))

# Scraping each product's reviews     
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')  
for product_url in product_urls[15:]:
    try:
        driver.get(product_url)
        sleep(5)
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html')
        for i in range(4):
            try:
                list_of_reviews.append(soup.select(f'#review-preview-toggle-{i}')[0].getText().strip())
            except:
                continue
        while(True):
            try:
                next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reviews"]/div[2]/nav/ul/li[position() = last()]/a[contains(@href, "https")]')
                if next_button != None:
                    next_button.click()
                    sleep(5)
                    html = driver.page_source
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html')
                    for i in range(4):
                        try: 
                            list_of_reviews.append(soup.select(f'#review-preview-toggle-{i}')[0].getText().strip())
                        except:
                            continue
            except Exception as e:
                print('finsish : ', e)
                break
    except:
        continue

scrapedReviewsAll = pd.DataFrame(list_of_reviews, index = None, columns = ['reviews'])         
scrapedReviewsAll.to_csv('scrapedReviewsAll.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('scrapedReviewsAll.csv')
conn = sql.connect('scrapedReviewsAll.db')
df.to_sql('scrapedReviewsAllTable', conn)
```

**TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given**
**in line product = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH(f'//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[{i}]/div/a')))**
**I keep getting this error while running the program..How this typeerror get solved??**

Comment: It's supposed to be `EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, somestring)`.

Comment: You're doing `By.XPATH(somestring)` hence your error.

Comment: Don't cram everything into one line of code. Doing so does not help anyone and as you've seen, makes debugging harder.

Comment: `product = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[{i}]/div/a')))`

Comment: Thankyou for your solution but this is creating another error- TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given in the same line

Answer (score 1):

try to change the code scraping the href to be as following:

```
# Scraping each product's urls | 16,064 products
for url in urls:
    driver = driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\dell\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(5)
    for i in range(1, 65):
        product = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='content']//div[contains(@class,'search-listings-group')]//ul//li['"+str(i)+"']/div/a")
        product_urls.append(product.get_attribute('href'))
```